# Getting non-english string (title) from DOM and passing it to e-mail in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, dom, encoding

I have this simple bookmarklet to send link by mail:

```
javascript:location.href='mailto:?SUBJECT='+document.title  +'&BODY='+escape(location.href);
```

The problem is that it doesn't handle non-English titles. For example the - e-mail subject for the following page will contain garbage.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Заголовок</title>
</head>
<body>

The title of the document is: 
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write( document.title);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What should I change to get it working with other languages/encodings ?

Comment: We also had this problem. I am afraid there is no general solution for all languages which works for all email clients, like older Outlook versions.

Comment: You're probably right, since none of 2 answers below doesn't solve the problem (at least not for Outlook 2003). Have you found solution for Outlook 2003? Does the "encodeURIComponent" solution works for newer versions of Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

`javascript:location.href='mailto:?SUBJECT='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)  +'&BODY='+encodeURIComponent(location.href);`

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:location.href='mailto:?SUBJECT='+encodeURIComponent(document.title)+'&BODY='+encodeURIComponent(location.href)
```